# Visual Studio 2013 CodeLens Authors not Showing Up

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, codelens

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Git, and I have CodeLens enabled so that I can see references, authors, changes.. etc. The problem is that the only thing that is showing up is the references. 
[image]
I went to Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > CodeLens and found all the textboxes checked. 
[image] 
 
Any ideas how I can Show Authors?

Comment: Is your TeamExplorer showing git repo properly?

Comment: Yeah it is working perfectly fine. This is the only feature that does not seem to work correctly.

Comment: I have silimar problem but I see the action that caused this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496004/code-lens-not-working-properly-after-interactive-rebase

Comment: @MsYvette Yes I do. I upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and the feature seems to be working fine there. Visual Studio 2013 still has the issue.