# Code Lens not working properly after interactive rebase

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-rebase, codelens

In VS2015 all the code metadata from git displayed in the code via the CodeLens functionality regarding the author and changes disappeared after I did git rebase -i and ammended commits to correct the author name (a typo in git configs in one of my machines). The same happened after force pushed the corrected repo and pulled to another machine with different version of IDE - VS2013. In Team Explorer I can see all the relevant information and all the other git intergrations functions work fine as well. What can cause this? What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the latest updates solves this problem. I haven't used aforementioned repository in a while so I can't tell which update solves the problem, but I am certain that:

- The bug is fixed in VS 2013 update 5
- Many CodeLens / git integration related bugs were solved in VS 2013 update 2

So I am guessing that both VS 2013 and 2015 with updates released after VS 2013 update 2 should work correctly.