# Rename of Visual Studio Solution Loses Git Tracked Changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, solution

When I rename my Git controlled Visual Studio solution, I lose all the changes. An error appears in the output window that says something like `<new-solution-name>.VC.opendb can't be opened`. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't rename all the solution related files. The fix is to edit `.gitignore` (manually or within VS) to rename the missed files. The missed files will have the old solution name. Rename them to the new name.

Before:

```
/<old-solution-name>.VC.VC.opendb
/<old-solution-name>.VC.db
/<old-solution-name>.sln
```

After:

```
/<new-solution-name>.VC.VC.opendb
/<new-solution-name>.VC.db
/<new-solution-name>.sln
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but since you figured some git + visualstudio problems would you be so kind and take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496004/code-lens-not-working-properly-after-interactive-rebase and give some insight?